# Fixed box with scroll bars?

Tags: css

i have some help text that i want the user to always see, even if they have scrolled to the bottom of the form.

i currently have it styled like so:

```
/********** help text ********************/
.fixed-box {
    position:fixed;
    top:100px;
width: 100%;
   overflow:auto;
}
```

it works awesome! when i scroll down it stays with me! however when there is more text that the page can handle it gets cut off on the bottom. is there any way to ensure the help text to always be on the top, while still allowing the user to scroll down to see the rest of it?

http://jsfiddle.net/uWY5S/

in the example above, the text is always on the top of the page when i scroll, which is awesome! but it's cut off and the user can never get to read the last of it if the main page content is not large enough :(

Comment: a jsfiddle would be helpful

Comment: It isn't particularly clear what you need - could you supply some additional information please?

Comment: sure! i'll do one now! thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.fixed-box {
    position:fixed;
    top:5px;
    width: 100px;
    overflow:auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uWY5S/3/

Comment: thanks! was there anything else you chaged? it seems to work in your example, but it's still does not work in my application

Comment: Nope. Just added the height. There is probably some other calss that overrides this box. Use Developer Tools (usually F12) to check what CSS is applied. Also, try adding `!important`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having another container dom inside the fixed dom:

```
<div class="fixed">
  <div class="fixed-wrapper">
    <p>I scroll!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {height:100%;}
.fixed {position:fixed; height:100%; width:200px; background-color:black;}
.fixed-wrapper {position:relative; overflow-y:auto; height:100%;}
p {color:white; height:3000px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `bottom:__px` to your fixed-box class CSS.

```
.fixed-box {
  position:fixed;
  top:5px;
  bottom:20px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/uWY5S/4/